# iOS property Observer in Objective C (String or dictionary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm building a property observer (Key-value-Observing) for my app. The ideal is to monitor strange in value for a value (String or Dictionary). I have wrote this in viewDidLoad

```
@interface BarScannerViewController () <AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate>
{
    NSMutableDictionary *scanTrackingNumbers;   
}
```

and in viewdidload

```
[scanTrackingNumbers addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"scanTrackingNumber" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

[scanTrackingNumbers setValue:@"test123455" forKey:@"scanTrackingNumber"];
```

and implement the method

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context{

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"scanTrackingNumber"]){
        NSLog(@"scanTrackingNumber Changed %@",change);
        NSLog(@"scan12335 %@",scanTrackingNumbers);
    }
}
```

I don't know why it is not working (noting print to the console log). What might be wrong with the code?

Comment: you should have forgot to initialise the member `scanTrackingNumbers` as @Raegtime said.

Answer (score 2):

try `setObject` instead of `setValue` "I don't know if it matter"
Also,make sure the dictionary initialized

write this before adding the observer

```
self.scanTrackingNumbers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

simpler way

```
self.scanTrackingNumbers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

simplest way

```
self.scanTrackingNumbers = @{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot forgot to initialize the dict. Do you have any ideal how can we modify for Array or collection of object?

Comment: you mean to edit specific object in the array?? is that what you mean

Comment: there are 2 ways the first using RactiveCocoa "subscribeNext", the other way by using NSPredicate to filter the array to get you object based on your statements

Comment: Yes to monitor change made to array for triger action regaring. Add. Delete. Edit. ... do know any reference for the 2nd? Want to build something natural

Comment: What you looking for is two-way binding and you can achieve this by:  https://www.raywenderlich.com/123108/bond-tutorial

Comment: Appreciate! will dig into that. Btw We have Reactive Cocoa, ReactiveKit ... what is the recommend library?.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the Dictionary :-D

```
scanTrackingNumbers = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Comment: thanks, My bad new initialise the variable! how can we modify for simple string?

Comment: do you know how can we monitor an array has change (edit, remove, add..)?

Comment: Subclass NSMutableArray ... override the addObject, removeObject... methods :-)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example or reference that we can follow?